# Neo4j Overview Dashboard returns wrong node/relationship/property counts?

Tags: neo4j

I've created a Neo4j GraphDB via Java with the EmbeddedDatabase. When I saw my ID's I thought that something is wrong since they are way up.

The graph has only inserts, no deleted or updates yet. And I see that the Overview Dashboard reports 13182 nodes and 24785 relationships. Any idea why this is so high?

When querying all my nodes and relationships, I see what I expect. I just find it strange that without any deletes, the id's are so high. Is this normal behaviour.

P.s.: I'm running Neo4j 2.0.0 M003

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The dashboard is not accurate as it does not show real count of nodes, rels and props. Indeed it shows the highest id in use for nodes, rels and props. Neo4j 2.0.0M3 seems to allocate ids blockwise, that's why you get the difference. If you delete some stuff in the db the highest id in use might stay at the same level, also a source if inaccuracy.

If you need the real count of nodes, you can use

```
start n=node(*) return count(n)
```